# How to sort a dictionary first by value then by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary

`d={'g':1,'w':1,'h':3}`

First, I want to sort value then by key, so the final output should look like this

`d={'h':3,'g':1,'w':1}`

Comment: If you want to sort a dictionary then you better be using python3.6 or better.

Comment: `print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))` ?

Comment: You take steps as ->sortbyValue->sortbyKey or directly sortbyKey it remains the same. What do you want to achieve with the intermediate step

Comment: I want to sort the dictionary by value after that if 2 or more keys have the same value I want to sort them according to the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Python 3.6 the dicts are ordered, but to be sure one needs to use `OrderedDict` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d={'g':1,'w':1,'h':3}

o = OrderedDict(sorted(((k, v) for k, v in d.items()), key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0])))
print(o)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('h', 3), ('g', 1), ('w', 1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python 2 you can do this with a custom cmp function:

```
def compare(a,b):
  if a[1] < b[1]:
    return 1
  elif a[1] > b[1]:
    return -1
  else:
    if a[0] < b[0]:
      return -1
    elif a[0] > b[0]:
      return 1
    else:
      return 0

d={"h":3,"g":1,"w":1}
items = d.items()
items = sorted(items, cmp=compare)
print items
```